# Evaluation of env variable in Laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, environment-variables

Sorry, pretty simple question:
I can't find any resource that explains the order of evaluation of the ENV variable in Laravel... Usually in Spring Boot if I define a variable in the `docker-compose` I know for a fact that it overrides the `application.properties` value.. is the same in Laravel?

E.g.:
**.env**

```
DB_HOST = A
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
environment:
    - DB_HOST = B
```

in the application, is guarantee that `DB_HOST` is `B`?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, to be sure about this, create a simple route like [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/0296bb63e1d465bcfff1f84f00313aeb26a2c84b/routes/web.php#L16-L18) and return `return env('DB_HOST');` so you can see the actual value is going to be `environment` eventhough it is defined in `.env` with other value.

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes I've done it, but I just want to be "sure" about it, like if is written somewhere in the docs or something like this

Comment: I don't remember seeing this in the documentation, so _no_ would be my answer.

Comment: [This](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#environment-based-configuration) is the only thing about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At time of writing Laravel uses [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Env.php) dotenv environment. The key behaviour of this is determined by line:

```
static::$repository = $builder->immutable()->make();
```

Immutable, as described in [the official dotenv repository](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/tree/v5.2.0), means that existing environment variables are not overwritten. Therefore the variables that docker-compose sets which are part of the container environment will not be overwritten by .env.

However since this is inferred by digging in the code and not explicitly documented (as far as I can tell), I think you need to treat it as undocumented behaviour and if you are relying on this then be vigilant before upgrading Laravel versions to make sure it has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the variables that are defined in the .env are returned first. They are stored on config/ files as well. In your case it's stored on config/database.php file.
In my case `env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')` it's this code.
What's it's saying basicly is that you get the value stored from the variable DB_HOST on .env, otherwise return the defaul value specified which is `127.0.0.1`

Edit: As specified in the comments, you can always testing by using dd() or return env(DB_HOST); and you will get the result.

Comment: what does this have to do with what I asked?